# Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation system shown in its augmented matrix form:
 However, this is the one solution for $a = \pm \sqrt{2}$ (from what I can see). So is there really any $a$ such that there are two different solutions? If you a smart enough to solve it - please take me through the process, like how you engage the problem :)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2x%2B(3%2Ba)y%2B2z%3D2%2Ba+and+x%2Ba*y+%2B+z+%3D+a+and+a*x%2B2y%2B2*a*z%3D0) says that you computed the solution incorrectly, can you share your work, please?

Comment: Thanks for the input, Viktor. However, it is correct :) Try substituting the solution back into the equations and you will see it :))

Comment: Why did you delete the matrices? Your question makes no sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be TWO solutions, as the set of solutions $S$ is either empty (when the ranks of the matrix  and of the augmented matrix are different), or  an *affine subspace*, of codimension  this common rank.

If you only mean (at least) two different solutions, it is equivalent to $\dim S >0$, i.e. the codimension (or the common rank of the matrix and the augmented matrix) is $<3$.

Anyway, when you divide by some coefficient in a row operation, it is always under the assumption this coefficient is $\ne 0$, so when it is $0$, you should examine the linear system before dividing.

Comment: They don't say *exactly* two solutions. Just two *different* solutions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: As the O.P.  wrote two in upper case, I interpreted it as meaning ‘exacrtly two’. Anyway, the end of the first sentence implicitly gives the answer. Probably I should make things quite clear.

Comment: you are right, these uppercase are ambiguous.

Comment: Yea, I see the problem with emphasizing two.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of the system is $a(a-3)$.

With $a=0$,

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2&3&2&2\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&2&0&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
is impossible ($2\ne2\cdot0+\dfrac32\cdot0$)
and with $a=3$,
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2&6&2&5\\
1&3&1&3\\
3&2&6&0
\end{array}\right]
$$ as well ($5\ne2\cdot3$).

Hence for other values of $a$, the solution is always unique.

---

**By Gaussian elimination:**

We subtract the second row

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2&3+a&2&2+a\\
1&a&1&a\\
a&2&2a&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
to obtain a scrambled echelon form
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
0&3-a&0&2-a\\
1&a&1&a\\
0&2-a^2&a&-a^2
\end{array}\right].
$$

which we reorder as

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1&a&a&1\\
0&a&2-a^2&-a^2\\
0&0&3-a&2-a\\
\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: Wow - thanks! Great. So to answer the question: "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions": it does not depend on a, but two different solution sets are obtainable. Is that correct, sir?

Comment: Because your Guassian part did not seem to make any assumptions about a

Comment: @Dip: sorry, can't make sense of your comments.

Comment: Alright, let me try to rephrase it. Try to answer the question "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions" directly. You seem to make no assumptions about a in your answer but found "another" solution set. So would "t does not depend on a, but two different solution sets are obtainable" be a correct answer to "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions"?

Comment: The main question is about finding a value of a such that there are two different solutions. And since it seems like you make no assumptions about a in your Gaussian part, I am wondering what your direct answer to ""Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions" would be.

Comment: @Dip: there is no difference between the discussion by determinant or by Gaussian elimination as regards the results.

Comment: But how would you answer "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions"? That is what I am trying to answer and your answer was a step on the way to answering that question. However, I am still not sure how to answer it. Therefore, I am asking what you would answer. Is it correct that it does not depend on a, but two different solution sets are obtainable? I hope you can make sense of my comment. So again, I am asking you to answer "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions" - notably what number a you find.

Comment: Except for the questions in the comment above, your answer is good and I will indeed hit "accept" after being able to directly answer "Find constant a such that the linear equation system has two different solutions" - like finding the value of a, if there is any.

Comment: @Dip: I have unambiguously stated for which values of $a$ the solution is not unique: NONE.